# CryptProtectData fails with error "File not found" when the user profile is not loaded

Tags: winapi, encryption

Calls to CryptProtectData with flag CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE fail with error code ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when the user profile is not loaded.

Someone reported this issue here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spatdsg/2006/01/04/crypt-calls-failing/

I encounter the same error on Windows 2008 R2 with an iis process running under a specific user. Loading the user profile solves the problem.
Once the profile is present on the disk (C:\Users\account_name), the error does not occur anymore, unless the profile directory is deleted.

Is this an expected behavior or is it a bug?

The API documentation doesn't say that a user profile has to be loaded and I do not see why a profile is required for machine-wide encryption. As a result, this API is totally unusable without a loaded profile.

**UPDATE**

Further investigations show that the call to CryptProtectData triggers the following actions:

- registry query for the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<sid>\ProfileImagePath` to extract the profile path
- read of the file `<profile path>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\<sid>\Preferred`

If the profile key is missing, or the path unusable, the function fails.
However, if the path is simply writable, the required files are created and the call succeeds.

So the API requires at least a writable profile path. The user profile does not have to be loaded when the call occurs, but it has to have been loaded at least once before, for the registry key to exist.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `CryptProtectMemory` instead?

Comment: `CryptProtectData` is used because the data are persisted to a file. I have tested `CryptProtectMemory` for curiosity and it works without the user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will try to access the key stores in the user profile, and it will fail because its not loaded. Keys are usually in files, so NTFS permissions can be used to restrict access to users. Read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/f5cs0acs(v=vs.140)) for more info. Although machine-level RSA key containers are available to all users, they can be secured with NTFS Access Control Lists (ACLs) so that only required users can access them.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Further tests show that the system has to read and write to AppData directory of the profile during the call. I think that this behavior should be stated in the documentation as loading the user profile requires privileges that make the function unusable in some contexts.